# Android Delete multiple items from ListView

Tags: android, listview

How do you delete multiple rows from a listview using the code below and I'm using MultiChoiceModeListener.

MainActivity

```
list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
        list.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new MultiChoiceModeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode,
                    int position, long id, boolean checked) {
                // Here you can do something when items are selected/de-selected
                final int checkedCount = list.getCheckedItemCount();
                // Update the title in the CAB
                mode.setTitle(checkedCount + " Selected");

            }
    @Override
            public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.menu_clear:
                    deleteSelectedItems(item.getItemId());
                    mode.finish();
                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
                }
            }
            public void deleteSelectedItems(int id) {
                adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(id)); //The method remove(Object) is undefined for the type ListViewAdapter
            }
```

ListViewAdapter

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    // Declare Variables
    Context context;
    String[] rank;
    String[] country;
    String[] population;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    View itemView;

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context, String[] rank, String[] country,
            String[] population) {
        this.context = context;
        this.rank = rank;
        this.country = country;
        this.population = population;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return rank.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // Declare Variables
        TextView txtrank;
        TextView txtcountry;
        TextView txtpopulation;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false);


        txtrank = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rank);
        txtcountry = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.country);
        txtpopulation = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.population);


        txtrank.setText(rank[position]);
        txtcountry.setText(country[position]);
        txtpopulation.setText(population[position]);

        return itemView;
    }
```

**EDITED**

```
@Override
            public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.menu_clear:

                    int count = adapter.getCount();
                    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                     adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(i));
                    }
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();//The method remove(Object) is undefined for the type ListViewAdapter
                    mode.finish();
                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
                }
            }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I'm trying to delete multiple rows from a listview.

Comment: That is not a question.

Comment: Sorry, just edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

in your `onItemCheckedStateChanged` you keep track of all the positions or id's that were checked (in a list or something).

then when a certain menu option is clicked you loop through all the positions or ids and delete them from your dataset.

after you deleted them call `notifyDatasetChanged` on your adapter

Comment: So you mean everything will be done inside deleteSelectedItems(int id) class?

Comment: well thats not a class thats call a method but no you dont have to do it there. make a for loop in your `onActionItemClicked` and loop the the list of id's and just pass the id to that method then remove the item from your dataset

Comment: I got this error The method remove(Object) is undefined for the type ListViewAdapter. What do I have to do ? Please help